# Android Socket don't send multiple packets

Tags: android, sockets, server, client

i've a problem.

I take the output stream from a connected Socket

```
outStream = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
```

And I send data to the server whit

```
private void send(final Object data){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            client.Send(data);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

That call "client.send(Object data)" content in another class.

```
    public void Send(Object data) {
    try
    {
        outStream.print(data);
        outStream.flush();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Disconnect();
    }
}
```

If I click on button for send data I receive correctly the data from the client, but if I click another time to the button, the Server doesn't receive the data...

Server (where I process data)

```
    Private Sub ReceiveCallback(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim socket As Socket = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, Socket)
    Dim received As Integer = socket.EndReceive(ar)
    Dim dataBuf As Byte() = New Byte(received - 1) {}
    Buffer.BlockCopy(_buffer, 0, dataBuf, 0, dataBuf.Length)

    If dataBuf.Length = 0 Then
        Disconnect(socket)
    Else
        OnDataReceived(socket, dataBuf)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And you are reading it how?

Comment: Whit Vb.NET Server, whit Async Socket, but I'm sure that the problem isn't the server

Comment: @EJP I've added the Server code :P

Comment: try adding end of line character. outStream.print(data+"\n");

Comment: Is equal to outStream.println?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting some kind of an exception and ignoring it:

1. Print the stacktrace when you get an exception.
2. Don't use `PrintWriter` over a network, as it swallows exceptions. Use `BufferedWriter`.
3. Don't catch `Exception` where `IOException` or some other more specific exception would have done.

I'm also wondering why you're creating a new thread to send. It shouldn't be necessary in most cases.